# How to send a boolean using RestKit?

Tags: ios, json, core-data, restkit

My RestKit App fails when it sends it's Core Data object because the produced JSON has `1` or `0` for a Boolean attribute value instead of true or false. The server doesn't like it.

The conversion happens in `JSONKit.m` at line 2723, where the code does something like:

```
if (object == (id)kCFBooleanTrue) { /*... yield "true" */ }
else if (object == (id)kCFBooleanFalse) { /*... yield "false" */ }
/* else yield integer */
```

The comparison fails here. My Core Data object apparently stores it's true value as `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` instead of `[NSNumberWithBool:YES]` (which I was surprised to find out that they result in a different object despite both printing as `1` by the debugger).

Note that I set that boolean attribute with:

```
myManagedObject.boolFieldValue = myUISwitch.on;
```

Where `boolFieldValue` is a property defined by MOgenerator, with the setter being:

```
-(void) setBoolFieldValue:(BOOL)value_ {
  [self setBoolField:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value_]];
}
```

Is there a way to force the output of the 1 value as true?

Comment: Where are you actually creating your JSON?

Comment: RestKit does, using it's mapping magic.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a Restkit based project, I am also using the Core Data integration.
I have boolean fields as well and don't have such issue.

- For my NSManagedObject, my property is defined as a NSNumber.
- In Core Data, the corresponding attribute is defined as an Integer16 (can't remember why I didn't pick Boolean, but that may be I had the same problem as you have)
- To set my boolean, I am using something like:

`[myObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value] forKey:@"booleanAttribute"];`

Comment: So that suggests a bug in my code somewhere. I'll need to investigate a bit more then.